# How to display all the dates between multiple two dates in a table?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, difference

I want to display all the dates between two dates for a particular record

And this is the table :

```
ID Start_Date End_Date

1 2013-01-14 2013-01-18
2 2013-02-01 2013-02-04
```

and now i want to get all the dates between from date and to date.

Expected output

```
ID Date
1 2013-01-14
1 2013-01-15
1 2013-01-16
1 2013-01-17
1 2013-01-18
2 2013-02-01
2 2013-02-02
2 2013-02-03
2 2013-02-04
```

guide me to write query for that with out creating any extra tables.

I have already tried this following query

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2012-02-10' and '2012-02-15'
```

its working fine for single record. but i want get all the date intervals from my table

**Updated**

i have 6 qty of chairs for all days. So one user book 3 chars on 2013-01-14 to 2013-01-18 another person book 2 chars on 2013-01-17 to 2013-01-20. So my expected output shown below.

```
ID Date         Available
1 2013-01-14     3
1 2013-01-15     3
1 2013-01-16     3
1 2013-01-17     5 
1 2013-01-18     5
1 2013-01-19     2
1 2013-01-20     2 
1 2013-01-21     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
  select
  t.id,
  DATE_FORMAT(a.Date,'%Y-%m-%d') as Date
  from (
    select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
  ) a
  join test t on a.Date between t.Start_Date and t.End_Date
  order by t.id,Date
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c6e6/7)**

Comment: i met another one task. i want to get the availability from this dates. so can you please guide me

Comment: Oh, I like your answer way better than mine.

Comment: @NathanSrivi please provide sample data and expected output. Or better create a new question with the details.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i have update new question to http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101157/how-to-display-all-the-dates-between-multiple-two-dates-in-a-table. guide me

Comment: @NathanSrivi could you explain a bit on `Available`, not sure I understand this part.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty  do you check that link

Comment: Yes but still did not get, please add some more description so that it becomes clear to all.

Comment: for eg : i want to build hotel booking type of system. so i am the owner of the hotel and i have 6 rooms. every day 6 rooms are available. if any rooms booked means i want to show the availability to users.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty availability means remaining item or stock

Comment: And do you have a booking table ? Provide the schema on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101157/how-to-display-all-the-dates-between-multiple-two-dates-in-a-table#new-answer?newreg=7a801006ad1a4c68923dfc0e7f4431a6

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't know your specific use case, but this feels ripe for more optimization.  However, how about this?

```
 select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) selected_date from
 (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where (selected_date between '2012-02-10' and '2012-02-15') OR
      (selected_date between '2012-03-10' and '2012-03-15') OR
      (selected_date between '2012-04-10' and '2012-04-15')
```